# iOSアプリからの画像挿入不可

Tags: ios, wordpress

CentOS7にDockerコンテナのCentOS7を作成してWordPress 4.7.2を動かしています。
httpサーバはApache/2.4.6です。PHP 5.4.16です。

iOSの「WordPress」アプリから画像挿入を行うと以下のようなエラー画面になります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

iOSの「PressSync」アプリから画像挿入を行っても以下のエラー画面になります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

画像挿入を伴わない投稿であれば問題なくできます。

phpの設定でも
memory_limit = 1000M
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
max_input_time = 60
とかなり高めに設定しています。

ブラウザからでもiPhoneの写真を直接メディアにアップするとHTTPエラーが発生しました。
縮小させてアップロードすると成功します。

解決方法をご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

==(自己解決しました)==
wordpressで使用しているDockerコンテナのフロントにnginxでproxy_passしています。
そのnginxの設定で
client_max_body_size 100M;
を設定するとできました。

Answer (score 1):

質問者様がnginxがインストールしている環境かはわかりませんので
同件かわかりませんがご参考です。
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/upload-fails-for-photos-taken-with-iphone/

nginx.confにを追加したら直ったとのことです。

```
client_max_body_size 20M;
```

PHP側のmemory_limit(/etc/php.ini)も確認された方が良いと思います。

Comment: apache2を使っています。php.iniのmemory_limitを-1に、post_max_sizeを20Mに、upload_max_filesizeを20Mに設定変更すると挙動が変わりまして、「操作を完了できませんでした。(WordPress.WordPressOrgXMLRPCApiError エラー1。」のエラーは出なくなりましたが、画像がアップロードされた場所に「(null)」という表示で投稿ボタンを押すと「メディアをアップロード中　メディアをアップロードしています。完了するまでしばらくお待ちください」との表示で終わりません。php.iniの設定で他の部分が関連しているのでしょうか？